# Spring @CacheEvict not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I've experience in Spring MVC, but first time using Cache. These are steps that I've done yet.

**Step : 1**

// In spring config

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("user");
}
```

// Cached Object

```
public class CachedUser {   
    private String username;
    private String token;
    // Public getter-setter
}
```

// AuthServiceImp

```
@Service
public class AuthServiceImp implements AuthService {

  @Override
  @Cacheable(value="user", key="#token")
  @Transactional
  public CachedUser loadUserDetailsFromDb(String username, String token) {
     // codes here
  }

  @Override
  @CacheEvict(value="user", key="#token")
  @Transactional
  public void removeUser(String username, String token) {
     // codes here
  }
}
```

// My Filter

```
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
  AuthService authService = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext())
            .getBean(AuthService.class);
  CachedUser user = this.authService.loadUserDetailsFromDb(username, authToken);
}
```

// Controller

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
  @Autowired
  private AuthService authService;
  @GetMapping("logout2")
  public ResponseModel logout(@RequestAttribute("username") String username,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(tokenHeader);
    authService.removeUser(username, token);
    return new ResponseModel(200,"Success",null);
  }
}
```

Whenever calling `loadUserDetailsFromDb` from `AuthenticationTokenFilter` it returns cached object (except in first call obviously). That means `@Cacheable(value="user", key="#token")` is working fine.

But even after I logged out and called `authService.removeUser()`,  calling `loadUserDetailsFromDb()` fetches the cached object. That means `@CacheEvict(value="user", key="#token")` is not working.

**Step: 2**

Referred [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/119059-cacheevict-not-working-when-there-s-cacheable-in-the-same-class) and moved `removeUser()` to another service ( say `CacheServiceImp implements CacheService` ), yet same problem.

**Step: 3**

Reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842637/cacheevict-not-working-while-calling-the-method-from-different-controller) and , by my understanding, moved `@Cache*` annotation to interface `AuthService`, got following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache
>   operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug
>   info?)

**Note :** Is the problem of not evicting, because I'm calling `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` methods from different classes. That is from `AuthenticationTokenFilter` and `AuthenticationController`

Comment: I think your implementation looks correctly. Perhaps you have forgotten @EnableCaching annotation in your configuration class?

Comment: `@EnableCaching` is there in my configuration class. And `@Cacheable` is working fine.

Comment: Further searching brought me this "**JDK ConcurrentMap which is enough for simple use cases but does not support the persistence or eviction policy**" from this post [link](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-cache-tutorial-with-ehcache/). Is this have something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with my code, head and internet, at last, I got this solved. It's a mistake in my Spring (Security) configuration, which I failed to post with the question.

**Mistake 1** :

In `SecurityInitializer` class

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {    
    public SecurityInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);
    }

}
```

As the project includes Spring MVC configuration, **the constructor must not be implemented**. So removed the constructor. This class, then, simply registers the springSecurityFilterChain Filter for every URL.

**Mistake 2:** ( THE REAL CAUSE OF ABOVE PROBLEM )

I've added my `AuthenticationTokenFilter` in two ways:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    // other overrides
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{ new AuthenticationTokenFilter() };
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Other config
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       //Other config
       httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter,
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

This made the filter to be called **twice**, one **inside Spring context** and the other as **usual Servlet filter**

So removed configuration inside `WebAppInitializer`

**Additional change**

Removed `@ComponentScan` from `WebSecurityConfiguration` because it's already in `SpringMvcConfig`. **This requires both configurations to be loaded in same context**. Done by following code.

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringMvcConfig.class, WebSecurityConfiguration.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
    // Removed filter registering from here (Mistake 2)
}
```

**At last, everything working FINE :)**